# Some modification regarding macro VBA code to delete row if a specific value exist

Tags: vba, excel, inputbox

I found on this website a macro to delete row if a specific value exists:
https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win001.htm
I am trying to modify a bit this code in order to be able to enter not only manually:

•   the column on which I want to do the modification  (for example A)

•   but also the string I want to delete.

That´s why I added manually the following datas in the code:

```
Dim Columnname As String
Dim DeleteStr As String
Columnname = Application.InputBox("Select Column", xTitleId, Type:=2)
DeleteStr = Application.InputBox("Delete Text", xTitleId, Type:=2)
            With .Cells(Lrow, " & Columnname & ")
If .Value = " & DeleteStr & " Then .EntireRow.Delete
```

The problem that I have when I run the code: I come across a windows which comes up “Run-time error 13” Type mismatch…Indeed it seems there is mismatch error on the line :
  With .Cells(Lrow, " & Columnname & ")

Unfortunately, I do not manage to identify where the mistake comes from. That would be fantastic if someone could help me.

Thank you so much in advance.
Xavi

Here below, please find my Code:

```
 Sub Loop_Example()
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim Columnname As String
Dim DeleteStr As String


Columnname = Application.InputBox("Select Column", xTitleId, Type:=2)
DeleteStr = Application.InputBox("Delete Text", xTitleId, Type:=2)

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'We use the ActiveSheet but you can replace this with
    'Sheets("MySheet")if you want
    With ActiveSheet

        'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
        .Select

        'If you are in Page Break Preview Or Page Layout view go
        'back to normal view, we do this for speed
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        'Set the first and last row to loop through
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

        'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

            'We check the values in the selected column in this example
            With .Cells(Lrow, " & Columnname & ")

                If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                    If .Value = " & DeleteStr & " Then .EntireRow.Delete
                    'This will delete each row with the Value "DeleteStr"
                    'in the seleted Column, case sensitive.

                End If

            End With

        Next Lrow

    End With

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to delete the rows with autofilter rather than using loops.

```
Sub test()
Dim Columnname As String
Dim DeleteStr As String
Columnname = Application.InputBox("Select Column", xTitleId, Type:=2)
DeleteStr = Application.InputBox("Delete Text", xTitleId, Type:=2)

With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range(Columnname & "1", .Range(Columnname & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, DeleteStr
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you need a check then first that value is present

Answer (score 1):

You don't need quotes around your variables:

```
    '...
    With .Cells(Lrow, Columnname)

        If Not IsError(.Value) Then

            If .Value =  DeleteStr  Then .EntireRow.Delete
            'This will delete each row with the Value "DeleteStr"
            'in the seleted Column, case sensitive.

        End If

    End With
    '...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient to delete in one go with Union of the qualifying ranges. And to loop only the necessary number of rows use the chosen column to determine the last row to determinate looping at. You can also re-write to use an efficient `For Each Loop` over the collection by setting a variable to hold your cells to loop over and using a `For Each` on that.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Loop_Example()
    Dim Firstrow As Long, Lastrow As Long, Lrow As Long, CalcMode As Long, ViewMode As Long, Columnname As String
    Dim DeleteStr As String, unionRng As Range, rng As Range

    Columnname = Application.InputBox("Select Column", , Type:=2)
    DeleteStr = Application.InputBox("Delete Text", , Type:=2)

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    With ActiveSheet

        .Activate

        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Columnname).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim loopRange As Range: Set loopRange =  .Range("C" & Firstrow & ":" & "C" & Lastrow)
        For Each rng In loopRange
            If rng.Value = DeleteStr Then
                If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, rng)
                Else
                    Set unionRng = rng
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```